# Where can I find Google Maps with a geopolitical overlay, as in colored countries?

Tags: google-maps

#### [FOUND IT](http://chartsbin.com/view/554), at last (as close as it gets)

---

I am looking for Google Maps (or any other interactive map) with a geopolitical overlay of the world (colored countries).

I'm not interested in Google API references to roll my own, I'm looking for something that's out there ready to play with.

#### I am basically looking for an interactive version of the map shown below.

[image: Geopolitical map of the World]

Comment: For the Google Maps version (Web Apps) or the Google Earth version (SU)?

Comment: another nice option - https://mapchart.net/detworld.html

Answer (score 2):

check the **[Travel Map Generator](http://www.29travels.com/map.php)**

color the countries to your likings and use the HTML code to play with. the generator offers only 600x300 as maximum size, but of course you can change the map size via the HTML code.

Comment: is this really all that's out there? it's sad.

Comment: pretty much so, and by default you're limited to 3 colours, well 2 (countries visited and countries to visit) plus default white, but i think you can play with the generated HTML code. some donkey work but it's fairly self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across a couple of political overlays for Google Earth...

- [World Countries as Polygons](http://bbs.keyhole.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showthreaded&Number=289717&site_id=1#import) (link to [KMZ file](http://bbs.keyhole.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=download&Number=140238&filename=289717-country.kmz)).
- A more detailed (and slower to load) [State-Province areas of countries](http://bbs.keyhole.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=315823&site_id=1#import) (link to [KMZ file](http://bbs.keyhole.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=download&Number=152408&filename=315823-LinktoState-ProvinceAreasofCountries.kmz))

Both of these are not very detailed when you zoom in, but if you switch on 'Borders and Labels' in the GE sidebar (and play with the transparency slider) you'll be able to superimpose the much more detailed GE borders.

[image]